# Qt Signal and Slot change value

Tags: qt, signals, slot

I am trying to learn Qt. I have a question about Signal and Slot mechanism.

```
void signalPopUpMessage(QString title, QString message, QString where, int typ);

emit signalPopUpMessage("DELETE DETECTOR", "Do you confirm to delete ID 01 ?", "detector", 0);
```

I want to change dynamically "ID 01" value. How to add a variable to the function?

Comment: Do you mean string concatenation? `QString( "some text %1" ).arg( 1 );`?

Comment: Yes, I meant concatenation. Your solution is ok for one variable. So, multiple variables I still use, sprintf function. For example;

sprintf(strTemp, "Do you confirm to delete ID 0%d %d", selection, sel2);

Is sprintf suitable for Qt or any idea better than this?

Comment: You can use the same code as QString( "some text %1 %2 %3" ).arg( 1 ).arg(2).arg(3);